# Dynamic SQL - copy all Tables from source database to destination database but UNION Output in destination database

Tags: dynamic, union

Here's the code but I am not sure how to add the union part to the query. I basically want copy all the tables, union all the tables and insert into a new table (destination database. Note all the tables have the same # of columns.

````
GO

DECLARE @DestinationDB VARCHAR(100)

SET @DestinationDB = 'AR02'

DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE Cur CURSOR
FOR
--Choose the list of tables you would like to copy to 
--New Destination Database
SELECT DISTINCT Table_Schema AS SchemaName
    ,Table_Name AS TableName
FROM information_Schema.Tables
WHERE Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'

OPEN Cur

FETCH NEXT
FROM Cur
INTO @SchemaName
    ,@TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DropTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Drop the Table in Destination if exists
    SET @DropTableSQL = '
      if exists (select * from ' + @DestinationDB + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where 
      TABLE_NAME = ''' + @TableName + ''' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @SchemaName + ''')
    drop table [' + @DestinationDB + '].[' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + ']'

    PRINT (@DropTableSQL)

    EXEC (@DropTableSQL)

    DECLARE @InsertSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Create new table and move data to it from Source Table
    SET @InsertSQL = 'SELECT * INTO ' + '[' + @DestinationDB + '].[' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + ']
    FROM [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + ']'

    PRINT @InsertSQL

    EXEC (@InsertSQL)

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM Cur
    INTO @SchemaName
        ,@TableName
END

CLOSE Cur

DEALLOCATE Cur```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problem: I need to append the tables using information schema tables. I do not want to specify the table names because each week the number of tables that gets created changes. In other words, one week I can have 96 tables and the next week I can have 100 tables or less. All the tables have the same number of columns and same columns names by default.

I need help creating a code that can union all the tables in order to have all records appended  and then  select into a new table. @bot